# How to draw a square using Javascript inside an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have done a lot of research and am not sure what the best approach is. I have a Kendo Grid (table) with 3 rows and 3 columns. I show a table *with only the first column* populated upon initial page load, and then I call and AJAX method to retrieve the rest of the data and replace the *whole table* with the new HTML.

```
----------------
| 01 |    |    |
| 02 |    |    |
| 03 |    |    |
----------------
```

And I replace the whole table with html that shows a table like this:

```
----------------
| 01 | hi | gr |
| 02 | hi | sd |
| 03 | fe | sf |
----------------
```

What I want to do though, is somehow "draw" a square over the empty columns in the initial empty table (with only the first column populated) so I can display a message in the center.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: With "whut" do you want to draw a square? Open to interpretation ... first thought: use CSS => `background-color background-image border`, second thought: which characters you like to output, to draw a square programmatically `▄ ■`?

Comment: I basically want to "overlay" my table with text that has "Loading..." in it. I want this element that I am going to overlay to be roughly in the center of my table. And I would like this element to remain roughly in the center of my table even if the window is resized. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example what are you looking for. There is 2 px error because of the cells border spacing or something but i'm too tired to find the solution for that now. Your div's height is equals with padding-top+height. Padding is needed to position your loading text vertically middle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        #mytable{
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 20%;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;

}
        #box{
            padding-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0px;
            z-index: 40;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 100px;
            height: 60px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td>Cat</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dog</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Parrot</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="box">
        Loading...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I basically want to "overlay" my table with text that has "Loading..." in it. I want this element that I am going to overlay to be roughly in the center of my table. And I would like this element to remain roughly in the center of my table even if the window is resized. Is this possible and is this answer a solution to this?

Comment: You can also give a background for it to hide the table or make it smaller than the table.

Comment: When you loaded the table data, just change the overlay's display property to "none";

Comment: You set the tables width and height as constant values, I am not sure how tall and wide my table is going to be (depending on the data that is loaded and the size of the window). How do I get around this?

Comment: You can't really. But yout can do display only the overlay and hide the table until it loading in then swap them. You can give it in % as well of course but that doesn't help you if you doesn't know how big is your table.

Comment: But you can give your table min-height and min-width, so if your data needs more it changes it, or you can do it manually with javascript when it's loaded. I'm dont understand it again.

Comment: Well I know the height, but not the width because the user could resize the browser window.

Comment: Your table can be different size after the load, but you cant know the size of it, until you download the data that tells you how big i has to be. An other option is to save how many data you have on the server and load it first(its a pretty small file), make the table to it's size and the overlay as well and the you load the lot of data into your table.

Comment: You just use % then. min-width: x%; on columns.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the table `loading` and mark it up with CSS.
When the AJAX call is `done()`, remove the `loading` class.

*However you do it with Kendo, this example is simply suggestive in jQuery.*

```
var table = $('#table');

table.addClass('loading');
$.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(function(){
    table.removeClass('loading');
});
```

Then for the CSS play around with transparent `background-color` in `rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.4)` or an [ajax loader](http://loading.io/) (hence the name).

```
table { position: relative; }
table.loading:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: 'loading';
    background-color: rgba(234,234,234,0.4);
    padding: 70%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The pseudo selector `:before` will create a hidden layer on the `table` and only be visible when your `loading` class is added. Once the AJAX call is `done()` you'll remove it again.

The horizontal centering can be done with `text-align` but the vertical centering is only possible with a `height` or `min-height`.

You can work around that issue by using a second hidden layer `:after`.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/8cycvgoh/)**